Ubuntu - can change password but not use it
I've been running into a problem with ubuntu where I'm forced to change my password every so many days due to a security requirement.  At login, it prompts me to change it, and i do.  If I then log out, or try to run sudo, my password doesn't work.  if I run passwd, I can change my password but the new one still won't work.
My workaround to fix this is,

reboot into recovery mode
drop to root
mount -o remount,rw /
vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
change AutomaticLoginEnable to false
reboot
login as usual and update password

I have no idea why this is happening or how to prevent it from happening in the future.
